# Get Exception to read asta file (.pp) using mpxj

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, mpxj

When I try to read asta(.pp) file using mpxj in java, then I am getting the error as shown below (even though, I already added the below shown code):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.30.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but it still gives the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;
    at net.sf.mpxj.asta.AstaDatabaseFileReader.read(AstaDatabaseFileReader.java:91)
    at net.sf.mpxj.asta.AstaDatabaseFileReader.read(AstaDatabaseFileReader.java:75)
    at com.visilean.cms.security.TestPrimavera.main(TestPrimavera.java:30)
```

Comment: This means that the version of sqlite-jdbc you're using doesn't provide the method. You may need to use a newer version, or an older version. You'll need to find out which version mpxj is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark points out in the comment below your question, MPXJ requires version 3.8.10.1 of the `sqlite-jdbc` jar. I suspect the interface has changed somewhat between that and the current 3.30.1 version. I will look at bringing that dependency up-to-date soon if I can.